# Real-space finite-difference approach for solving schrodinger equation

Tags: python, algorithm, physics

I've written a simple code to plot the eigenvectors of a particle confined to an infinite quantum well. I used real-space finite difference method. Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

L=12 #length of the well,unit:Ang
a0=0.52917721 #unit of length in atomic system, given in Ang
k=0 # quantum number

#Atomic unit conversion
L_au=L/a0

n=1000
h=L_au/n

c0=1/(h**2)
c1=-1/(2*h**2)

#kinetic energy
T=c0*np.diag(np.ones(n-1))+c1*np.diag(np.ones(n-2),1) \
            +c1*np.diag(np.ones(n-2),-1)

x=np.arange(0,L_au,h)

#Hamiltonian
H=T
val,vec=la.eigh(H)
plt.plot(x[:-1],vec[:,k])
```

The code is simple in its nature but when I plot it I don't get a well-normalized sinusoidal eigenstate. Here's the output:
[image: output]:

As you see its not normalized. I guess the vertical axis should be multiplied by a variable that depends on L. I don't know any hint is appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** Let me elaborate on what I mean by it's not normalized. In quantum physics, a wave function psi(x) is said to be normalized if this condition is true:

[image: Normalization condition]

So for normalization we need to make sure that the integral of the square of wavefunction over whole space adds up to 1. But that's not the case for the above diagram. I don't know if the problem is with my code or with my understanding of the problem.

Please see [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.3240), page 15, for more info.

**EDIT 2:** Actually, if it wants to be normalized the peak value of the diagram should be at 0.46 but in my case it's at about 0.046. So it sounds it'll need to be multiplied by a 10 to make it normalized. But I tried changing L and got different multiplication factors.

I know the question might still look vague to most of you. But if I want to tell everything in detail I'll need to write a book and that's not possible. But if you read the article mentioned above you'll get a good understanding of the code I've written.

Comment: Can you clarify what your actual question is? I don't know enough of the relevant physics to help, but if you're clearer about what you're asking for, perhaps somebody else will be able to.

Comment: Why do you think it's not normalized? `np.linalg.eigh` gives normalized vectors, you can test that with `np.linalg.norm(vec[:,k])` which gives one. Is there any other problem?

Comment: @Blckknght sorry, I know it's not clear enough. I'll edit the post

Comment: I see your problem now. The y-axis doesn't depend on distance `h` since `np.linalg.eigh` always gives normalized vectors (to unity) so it also gives these vectors if you set `c0=1` and `c1=-1/2`, but the x-axis obviously depends on `h`.

Comment: What I did to compensate this was numerical integration: `from scipy.integrate import simps` then calculate the integral of the probability density `prob = simps(vec[:,k]**2, x[:-1], h)` and normalize the wave function `plt.plot(x[:-1], vec[:,k]/prob**.5)`. Does this work?

Comment: @Michael Great! Thanks for explanation. I knew that something went wrong with the y axis because it wasn't scaled properly. After I followed your approach it gave the very exact shape.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code in detail, remember that differential equations alone are never sufficient to fully describe a physical model. Boundary condition play a very important often understated role.

For example, in the case of quantum systems (as here) it is precisely because of the fact that for a physical system the wavefunction is required to be normalized, that some possible solutions to the Schrödinger equation (SE) are not valid physically. It is thus the introduction of this boundary condition (normalized wavefunctions), and not the SE itself, that causes the solutions to be discrete.

In other words, the normalization in not built into the SE or anything, it still allows solutions that are not normalizable. (Btw, this is actually a useful property in some models.) Normalization
is something you have to check solutions to the SE for, and disregard the ones not valid as not physical.

Additionally, again about boundary conditions, did you take into account conditions at the edge of the potential well?